# Multiple jquery animate's with same speed and different height's complete the animation at the same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

So, I have multiple jquery animate's with the same speed and different height's and all of the animations are completed at the same time.

I'd like to know if there is a way to keep the original animation speed no matter what the distance is?

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/CEksN/ - Meaning that these would of course complete at different times.

( My problem isn't really how they all complete at the same time, but how their speeds vary )

---

FlabbyRabbit's answer got me to the right path. This is more or less what I was after

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/CEksN/12/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191358/jquery-animation-speed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I would go about it:

```
//Calculate length of time per pixel
var spp = 500/20;
$('#lt').animate({ height: '400' }, spp*400, 'linear');
$('#mm').animate({ height: '55' }, spp*51, 'linear');
$('#ss').animate({ height: '20' }, spp*20, 'linear');
```

Your updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CEksN/8/

Comment: I realized later on that I might have not thought about all of the aspects of this question especially with the example, but your answer gets me where I wanted to go with it. This is more or less what I was after. http://www.jsfiddle.net/lollero/CEksN/12

Comment: This might be a bit more useful: http://jsfiddle.net/CEksN/13/. The duration refers to the length of time to show the smallest element, but it should be easy enough to change it to the tallest.

Comment: Thanks! that might come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version, where the I've made a simple change to the height and speeds so that the ratio between the two is more obvious...

```
$('#lt').animate({ height: '400' }, 1600, "linear");
$('#mm').animate({ height: '200' }, 800, "linear");
$('#ss').animate({ height: '100' }, 400, "linear");
```

I've also made the animation linear so that you can see they do animate at the same speed.  Remove the "linear" parameter and it's not so even looking.  I'm afraid that's just the nature of easing.  It looks lovely, but it can cause a hell of a maths issue when it comes to synchronising things like you want.

Hope this helps :)